# Is there a way to tag an _answer_?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a number of answers which provide novel means of using Blender tools to achieve results I didn't think were possible. Sometimes I'm inclined to tag the answer with a tag like "tip", to make the answer more easily found. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Nope, I don't believe this is possible atm.

Comment: Well how about implementing the idea by editing a "header line" into selected answers, something like " **Tag**: a helpful technique"? Then doing a search for "helpful technique" would bring up all these helpful techniques in a single page that people could browse, say while on an extended layover at their least favorite airport?

Comment: These sorts of SE feature requests will likely get more attention from people who can answer (SE devs etc.) on the [network-wide meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK. <Tongue in cheek mode> But why do I care about all those other SE sites? </Tongue in cheek mode>. More seriously, this is partly a way to make sure that I don't make more of a fool of myself than I already seem by asking a question (or making a suggestion) whose answer starts out, "It's trivial to do that, just..."